# JSP not found when running Spring Boot in IDE, but works when running manually

Tags: spring, jsp, intellij-idea, spring-boot, http-status-code-404

I have a java web application code (checked out from remote git server - others users dont have my problem) and imported it into IntelliJ (newest edition), I performed from IDE following steps: maven clean install, run (its spring boot application so there are no arguments or parameters to configure in run configuration to set - I compared it with settings from IDE on ohter computer - no differences) and then I sent a request to server with resul "404 - /WEB-INF/../some.jsp not found) but in unzipped WAR this file exists ! Moreover, when I run this war manually (java -jar app.war) my request was sent successfully with positive result - view was displayed. So, there is definitelly sth wrong with IDE. I tried almost everything: i reinstalled IDE, I deleted .m2 repository, I checked out code again, I tried with different IDE version but problem still arrives. What may be wrong ?

Comment: Are you using your own local server ?in server work,temp folders have you checked?Or cleaned those folders?

Answer (score 0):

maybe your application use dispatcher servlet ,so your request mapped and you cannot request to exact path of jsp file and your browser show 404 not found
,check your web.xml that has like this code

```
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
```

and search *.xml file that use jspResolver or somthing like this

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

if you find it, you should request for example like this

http://localhost:8080/nameofyourapp/index

instead of http://localhost:8080/nameofyourapp/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot does not include Jasper by default and therefore JSP rendering doesn't work unless you explicitly include the library:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The below libs are also necessary, hope you have already added:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
   <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-logging-juli</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
   <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
</dependency>
```